# Move Section of Canvas to Other Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two canvases, let's say Canvas A and Canvas B. The user uploads a file and it gets put on Canvas A, which I already have done. Once that happens, I want to start copying sections of Canvas A to Canvas B.

I have tried doing this

```
source = a.getContext('2d');
b.drawImage(source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height);
```

but that copies the whole thing. So my question is, how do I copy a part of Canvas A to Canvas B.

Edit:

I have also tried...

```
var imgData=atx.getImageData(10,10,20,20);
btx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

but that just copies the imgData back onto Canvas A at (0, 0).

Comment: Use the 9(!)-parameter version of [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Comment: What do you mean by this? Do you have a practical application of this that I can learn from?

Comment: Use your first snippet, but instead of drawing the canvas context, draw the canvas directly.`b.drawImage(a, 0, 0, a.width, a.height)`

Comment: For more info on canvas 2D `drawImage` see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage and many more  linked resources browser related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, [`b.drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) takes a `CanvasImageSource` as its first argument, not a Context. Pass your entire `HTMLCanvasElement` in there.

`drawImage` takes nine arguments, and you're gonna need all of them. If you only use five, it's assumed that you're taking the *entire* source image and drawing it at your destination. The full signature is

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

`sx`, `sy`, `sw`, and `sh` define the rectangle you're copying from your source. `dx`, `dy`, `dw`, and `dh` define the rectangle you're drawing in at your destination. Note that `sw` and `sh` don't have to match up with `dw` and `dh`. If the source and destination rectangles don't have the same size, the copied image will be squashed or stretched to fit the destination rectangle.

I've made a snippet that lets you play around with `drawImage` to see what it's doing. It works best when you view it as a full page:

```js
const srcCanvas = document.querySelector('#source');
const srcContext = srcCanvas.getContext('2d');
const destContext = document.querySelector('#destination')
  .getContext('2d');

// The overlay canvas is where we draw the red rectangle. It's
// positioned directly on top of the source canvas.
const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay')
  .getContext('2d');
overlay.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
overlay.strokeStyle = 'red';

const inputs = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')
);
const lockScale = document.querySelector('#lockScale');
lockScale.addEventListener('change', () => {
  inputs[6].disabled = lockScale.checked;
  inputs[7].disabled = lockScale.checked;
  if (lockScale.checked) update();
});

// Grab an image and draw it on the source canvas...
fetch('https://picsum.photos/320/240/?image=451')
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(createImageBitmap)
  .then(bitmap => {
    srcContext.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    
// ...and only then start watching for changes in the input boxes.
// There's no point in spending cycles copying an empty canvas.
    inputs.forEach(i => {
      i.addEventListener('input', update);
    });
    update();
  });

function update() {
  if (lockScale.checked) {
    inputs[6].value = inputs[2].value;
    inputs[7].value = inputs[3].value;
  }
  const values = inputs.map(i => Number(i.value));
  
  destContext.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
  overlay.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
  overlay.beginPath();
  overlay.rect(
    // These adjustments move the overlay path off the boundary
    // between pixels so the rectangle border is a crisp 1px line.
    values[0] + 0.5,
    values[1] + 0.5,
    // JavaScript uses half-open intervals, which makes sense for
    // code. But for a visualization of graphics work, fully-
    // closed intervals are preferable. These adjustments make the
    // overlay rectangle exactly cover the pixels that will be
    // copied.
    values[2] - 1,
    values[3] - 1
  );
  overlay.fill();
  overlay.stroke();
  
  // The real drawing code of this snippet doesn't look like the
  // code you would actually use. We call apply() on drawImage()
  // so we can pass in the entire values array without listing out
  // every element.
  destContext.drawImage.apply(
    destContext, // We don't want to change what 'this' points to
    [srcCanvas].concat(values));
    
  // The spread operator provides a more elegant way of doing this:
  // destContext.drawImage(srcCanvas, ...values);
  // But it doesn't work with IE.
}
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 240px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.canvasbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="number"] {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: none;
  background: silver;
  color: black;
  width: 3em;
}

input[disabled] {
  color: silver;
  background: grey;
}

code {
  color: navy;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvasbox">
  <canvas id="source" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
  <canvas id="overlay" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="canvasbox">
  <canvas id="destination" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <code>
    destContext.drawImage(srcCanvas,
    <input id="sx" type="number" value="180">,
    <input id="sy" type="number" value="100">,
    <input id="sw" type="number" value="40">,
    <input id="sh" type="number" value="50">,
    <input id="dx" type="number" value="10">,
    <input id="dy" type="number" value="10">,
    <input id="dw" type="number" value="40">,
    <input id="dh" type="number" value="50">);
  </code>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="lockScale" type="checkbox">Lock scale
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Will test it when I'm at my computer.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response. When I use `btx.drawImage(a, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 1, 8, 8);`, it copies a rectangle from (8, 8) to (15, 15) [an 8*8 square] Even though the specified values in btx.drawImage, I specified (8, 8) to (8, 8) [or one pixel]. Why is this? Just to clarify, it is working, but I have no idea why. Also when I do btx.clearRect(4, 1, 4, 1); It should clear 1 pixel [at (4,1)] in canvas B, but it clears a larger area. Thanks!

Comment: `sw` and `sh` are _width_ and _height_, not "the opposite corner". The rectangle you copy has its top left corner at (`sx`, `sy`) and extends rightward `sw` pixels and downward `sh` pixels. If you want to grab the pixel at (8, 8), use `drawImage(a, 8, 8, 1, 1...)`. Same goes for the other methods that use rectangles.